# Why XCode Simulator show up so slowly?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I found Simulator show up very slowly. It takes me nearly 10 seconds to show the Simulator after building successfully by pressing Command + R, even with a new Project.

I'm using Mac Lion +  XCode 4.5.2

Comment: Could be too few RAM or too slow HDD. Or background processes. Or too slow CPU.

Comment: 10 seconds is maybe a bit much, but it easily takes 5 on my box.  Remember, after the app is built it must be "downloaded" to the simulator, in addition to the overhead of simply starting the simulator.

Comment: Based on a comment below, the OP's situation is the same as mine. Prior to the update to iOS 6 SDK and XCode 4.5.x, the Simulator would start in a tiny fraction of the time it took post-update. On my system, going from when the Simulator icon first appears to the window first appears on a cold start is about 14 seconds, and then 12 seconds for the warm starts. This is compared to about 3 seconds prior to the update. This machine has an SSD with ~20% free space, and a fair bit of free RAM. I'm mostly curious whether this is unique to my system, or just how the new simulator acts everywhere.

Comment: I was curious, so I tried starting the Simulator directly (not via an Xcode project), and the window first appears after about 1 1/2 seconds, and it's fully up by 3 seconds. Clicking 'Run' in Xcode (when the simulator is already running) results in the app already launching by the time I switch windows... so it appears that starting the Simulator, then starting the app by hand, takes probably half the time of Xcode starting Simulator+app.

Comment: Thanks Kitsune! You're right! It's because of the Simulator starting up so slow. If I don't quit Simulator by pressing Command + Q, next time it will be quite fast to build and run App in XCode by pressing Command + R.

Comment: @Kitsune Did you solve this problem? I'm seeing the same issue with my mbp (i7, 8gb ram, ssd).

Comment: @dallen Still present. Seems like you either have to get used to it being slow to start up, or get in the habit of not actually closing the Simulator like you used to be able to.

Comment: @Kitsune Mine is actually slow after start up too (faster after start up, but slower than previous versions). Have you tried using an older version of the simulator??

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when there is no memory or there is  a hang in the Xcode or the simulator, try to completely close the Xcode and the simulator i hope this will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The first time the simulator starts up tends to be much slower than subsequent startups. I'm using an SSD in my MacBook Pro and that helps as subsequent startups of the simulator are quite fast. It may also help you to change your derived data directory, typically ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData, to a RAM disk under File > Project Settings. I'm using Mountain Lion, Xcode 4.5.2 with the iOS 6 SDK and have 16 GB of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't think it's because of the machine. I'm using MacBook Air with SSD and 4G RAM. Originally, it's quite fast to show the simulator after being built. But it seems to become much slower after I installed iOS6 SDK.

Comment: I experienced the same thing when I upgraded to iOS6 and the corresponding Xcode release. It's likely something related to that (before the upgrade, the Simulator would launch in ~1 second).

Comment: I'm able to corroborate my experience with Activity Monitor by doing a purge, starting Xcode, starting iOS simulator, quitting simulator, starting simulator. The initial start of the simulator results in 793 page-ins. Subsequent starts result in 1 page-in for the simulator.